# Turning multi-line string into multi-element array using regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, newline, preg-match-all

I need to split the following string and put each new line into a new array element.

```
this is line a.(EOL chars = '\r\n' or '\n')
(EOL chars)
this is line b.(EOL chars)
this is line c.(EOL chars)
this is the last line d.(OPTIONAL EOL chars)
```

(Note that the last line might not have any EOL characters present. The string also sometimes contains only 1 line, which is by definition the last one.)

The following rules must be followed:

- Empty lines (like the second line) should be discarded and not put
  into the array.
- EOL chars should not be included, because otherwise
  my string comparisons fail.

So this should result in the following array:

```
[0] => "this is line a."
[1] => "this is line b."
[2] => "this is line c."
[3] => "this is the last line d."
```

I tried doing the following:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/^(.*)$/m', $str, $matches);
return $matches[1];
```

$matches[1] indeed contains each new line, but:

- Empty lines are included as well
- It seems that a '\r' character gets smuggled in anyway at the end of the strings in the array. I suspect this has something to do with the regex range '.' which includes everything except '\n'.

Anyway, I've been playing around with '\R' and whatnot, but I just can't find a good regex pattern that follows the two rules I outlined above. Any help please?

Comment: You can just pass `$matches` through `array_filter()` (`$matches = array_filter($matches);`) to get rid of the empty elements.

Comment: Combining all your answers below, I found preg_split('/\R/', trim($str)); to work!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split on the regular expression:

```
// Split on \n, \r is optional..
// The last element won't need an EOL.
$array = preg_split("/\r?\n/", $string);
```

Note, you might also want to `trim($string)` if there is a trailing newline, so you don't end up with an extra empty array element.

Comment: Thanks for the trim tip. I now use preg_split('/\R/', trim($str)); which works.

Comment: preg_split('/\R+/', trim($str)) is even better now! empty lines are not included thanks to the +

Answer (score 3):

There is a function just for this - `file()`

Comment: It's a string actually, not a file I need.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) would be the way to go... You can use an appropriate regexp to use any EOL character as separator.

Something like the following (the regexp needs to be a bit more elaborate):

```
$array = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $string);
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_split` function:

```
$array = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $string);
```